# where is the verb?

Tags: verbs, present-participles

Where is the verb in this sentence "We are going out to play".

Is it "are"?  If so what part of speech is "going"?

Thanks
Michelle

Comment: *Are* is the finite verb; *going* is the present participle of the verb *to go*.  These two words are combined to form the present continuous/progressive aspect.

Answer (score 2):

"are going" is the present continuous form of the verb "to go".  "We go out to play" could be read as a general statement, i.e. you don't play inside. "We are going out to play" means that you are presently in the act/motion of going out to play.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So if you were asking a student to identify the verb in that sentence would it be "are going"?

Comment: I would not ask a student to "identify the verb" in any sentence. I would ask them, possibly, to identify any **verbs** [plural] in the sentence. Not all sentences have precisely one word that is ***the** verb*.